# How to implement `cat` in Python

Tags: python, pipe

Could anyone please give a working example of `cat` implemented in Python? This program should read from stdin and write to stdout. The question I have is: How to read all the remaining data from stdin (not necessarily terminated by a newline)? Should I use nonblocking IO, turn off buffering, or do something else?

The C implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main()
{

    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;

    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(0, &set);

    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    char buf[1024];

    while (1) {
        select(FD_SETSIZE, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        int n = read(0, buf, 1024);
        if (n == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }
        write(1, buf, n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The test program:

```
import time

i = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
    i += 1
```

Expected result: Piping the test program to `cat.py` should output a number every 0.2 second. The result is as expected with the builtin `cat`, or with the C implementation above.

Comment: I think you should try inbuild python **sys** library  `import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()` and `sys.stdout`

Comment: Typically, `echo` reads from stdin & writes to stdout. `cat` will read from a file & write to stdout (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html). Just search on how to read from a file in Python.

Comment: @TusharNiras `sys.stdin.read()` returns a `str`. Do they work with `bytes` as well?

Comment: The standard streams are in text mode by default. To write or read binary data to these, use the underlying binary buffer. For example, to write bytes to stdout, use `sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc')`

Comment: @TusharNiras What methods should I call `on sys.stdin.buffer`? `read` or `readline` or sth else?

Comment: `print(open(filename, 'r').read())` is a common, minimal implementation of `cat`. Consider importing `sys` and using `sys.argv` to be able to pass filenames to the script as runtime arguments.

Comment: @Jules No that doesn't work with buffering. Try with the test program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right this isn't very painful.

```
import os
import select
import sys

while True:
    ready, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0.0)
    if sys.stdin in ready:
        data = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 4096)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), data)
```